# Time intelligence in BI tools

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence, powerpivot

In a language such as DAX, there is an entire page of [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax) related to (more-or-less) creating date tables of various start/end dates. For example:

> [`DATESMTD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax)    Returns a table that contains a column of the dates for the month to date, in the current context.

What are the main uses of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to create a slicer where you select a date and want to show the month-to-date, quarter-to-date, and year-to-date totals as separate metrics.

Instead of having to write the logic for these period-to-date metrics by hand, you can simply write:

```
TotalMTD = CALCULATE ( [Total], DATESMTD ( 'Date'[Date] )
TotalQTD = CALCULATE ( [Total], DATESQTD ( 'Date'[Date] )
TotalYTD = CALCULATE ( [Total], DATESYTD ( 'Date'[Date] )
```

Instead of having to write something more like this:

```
TotalQTD =
VAR SelectedDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR QuarterStart =
    EOMONTH ( SelectedDate, - MOD ( MONTH ( SelectedDate ) - 1, 3 ) - 1 )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Total],
        'Date'[Date] <= SelectedDate,
        'Date'[Date] > QuarterStart
)
```

---

For many more examples of time intelligence uses see here:

https://www.daxpatterns.com/standard-time-related-calculations/

Comment: thanks, could you show a graphic or something of how the above might look in Excel or PowerBI?

Comment: I create things like this all the time: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTVCm.png

Comment: awesome, thanks, could you show the same thing for what the date-filter/slicer looks like? Is this something where someone could enter in a start_date? end_date? Select from various 'checkpoint dates'? Basically, I'm just curious how this different than the static calculation of doing `YEAR(NOW()) - NOW()` for example for YTD.

Comment: In this case, the slicer is just for the end date (from a dropdown list) since the start date varies by measure. Your suggestion wouldn’t work since it’s an integer minus a datetime.

Comment: I see, so it would be like this then, if I'm understanding things correctly (using a SQL equivalent) -- https://imgur.com/a/7GFmuJI ?

Comment: Something like that. I think YEAR still returns an int rather than a date in SQL, right?

Comment: yea, exactly. I'm not sure whether it's part of the ISO standard, but I know mysql allows that comparing and casts(?) the integer to a year: https://imgur.com/a/wzcWOgZ.